# How do I display the list view change history in a user's form view? (Odoo 13)

Tags: listview, view, odoo

I use Studio tool to create a submenu like this with user: Nguyen Van A who have much information activity.

[image]

In the FORM VIEW of user (Nguyen Văn A). I want to show the history change of the user (Nguyen Van A) via the tab: (Lịch Sử) below like this.
[image]

How can I do that?

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can set a parameter `tracking=True` in fields you wanna track, then inherit `mail.thread`, the system will display any change in log note

Comment: Cảm ơn Nhật đã hỗ trợ. Mình có thể liên lạc với Nhật để hỏi chi tiết hơn được không?